# How get parent element attribute and child value from XML in java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file, for example:

```
<parent value="first">
  <child>Bill</child>
</parent>
```

I want to get at output: value=first,child=Bill
That means I need attribute from parrent element and value from child element.

I tried to do something like this:

```
List<Str> obj = new ArrayList<Str>();
NodeList nList  = doc.getElementsByTagName("parent");
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); ++i) {
    Element attrElement = (Element) nList.item(i);
    NamedNodeMap map = attrElement.getAttributes();
       for (int j = 0; j < map.getLength(); j++) {
            Node attribute = map.item(j);
            Node eNode = nList.item(j);
            Element name = (Element) eNode;
            obj.add(new Str(attribute.getNodeValue(), name.getElementsByTagName("child").item(0).getTextContent()));
       }
    }
```

In result i have Str with "null" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
      List<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
      NodeList nList  = doc.getElementsByTagName("parent");
      for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); ++i) {
          NamedNodeMap map = nList.item(i).getAttributes();
             for (int j = 0; j < map.getLength(); j++) {
                  Node attribute = map.item(j);
                  Node eNode = nList.item(i); // Use i value here that is the issue. 
                  Element name = (Element) eNode;
                  obj.add(new String("Value = "+attribute.getNodeValue() + ",Child=" + 
                      name.getElementsByTagName("child").item(0).getTextContent()));
             }
          }
```

Add one outer element,It works fine for multiple tags

```
<xml><parent value=first> 
    <child>Bill</child></parent> <parent value=second> <child>Steve</child>
</parent></xml>
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is a problem. I have more than one parent. Attribute changes, but child name stays like first. I wanted if
<parent value="first">
  <child>Bill</child>
</parent>
<parent value="second">
  <child>Steve</child>
</parent>

And the result I get: 
1) value=first,child=Bill
2) value=second,child=Bill

but value=second,child=Steve should be.

Comment: I copied yours xml. In both cases I get "Child = Bill"

Comment: Please see updated code near " Use i value instead of j that is the issue. "